# Is there a way to use environment variables for url and branch for materials in GOCD

Tags: git, pipeline, go-cd

Background: the release branch changes every time when we do a release, e.g. the release branch name like `release-100, release-101 ...`.

In my release pipeline, I want to make the `branch` attribute an environment for material, so we can use the `trigger with options` to edit this value dynamically. But I found it doesn't work with the following config:

```
"environment_variables": [
    {
      "name": "BRANCH",
      "value": "release-101"
    }
]
...
"materials": [
    {
      "url": "git_repo.git",
      "branch": "${BRANCH}",  # not work, and also #{BRANCH}
      "shallow_clone": false,
      "filter": {
        "ignore": [],
        "whitelist": []
      },
      "destination": "ansible-deploy",
      "auto_update": true,
      "type": "git",
      "name": "ansible-deploy"
    }
 ]
```

someone knows whether this is possible? Thanks.

BTW: you may advise to edit the material revision number when using `trigger pipeline with options`, but since the release branch will not contain commits after it's cut off, the GOCD can not found the revisions neither.